# Windows XP machine can't RDP into a W7Pro box - not sure why

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I'm getting the error:

"The client could not establish a connection to the remote computer.

The most likely causes for this error are:
1) Remote connections might not be enabled at the remote computer
2) The maximum number of connections was exceeded at the remote computer.
3) A network error occurred while establishing the connection.

The remote machine has been enabled, and the user has been added as an administrator as well as an RDP user. I am able to remote in with other machines on the network, including other XP boxes with NLA enabled. The user is able to RDP into other boxes, but when she tries to get into these machines it **instantly** fails, almost as if there is an entry in the host file redirecting it or something. Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Are you using the latest RDP client?  Have you tried disabling the NLA requirement on the remote machine?  Domain or workgroup?

Answer (score 2):

Update the XP machine to RDP 7 [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969084).